# Trigger custom function when `*Scratch*` is recreated

Tags: scratch-buffer

I would like to run a custom function whenever a new `*Scratch*` buffer is created because the last uninteresting buffer was killed.  I looked at both the C source code and `window.el` and it appears that `Lisp` has nothing to do with the `*Scratch*` buffer being displayed in a particular window, but I'm not 100% certain.  It appears as though `tem = Fother_buffer (buffer, Qnil, Qnil)` within `kill-buffer` is what leads to the creation of a new `*Scratch*` buffer.

Is there anything other than the `buffer-list-update-hook` that I could use to trigger my custom function when a new `*Scratch*` gets spawned?  I don't think that `replace-buffer-in-windows` is any help in this context.

[I don't really want to advise `get-buffer-create`.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function assigned to the variable `initial-major-mode` is *only* called when `*Scratch*` is created by Emacs (e.g., `startup.el`, or when certain criteria is met when killing a buffer).  It can be a custom function -- e.g., set the `major-mode` and do anything else under the sun.

```lisp
(setq initial-major-mode (lambda () (lisp-interaction-mode) (message "*scratch*")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `*scratch*` buffer isn't special; it's just a regular buffer with a fixed name. There are no special hooks just for it, so `buffer-list-update-hook` is the way to go.